# Post request with query params and body

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am making use of Retrofit to call the restful webservices in the android, I have come across the scenario like I need to pass query params and request payload object in the retrofit request, so I've tried something like this

```
@POST("actual url")
Call<ReceiptList> getData(@Query("limit") String limit, 
                              @Query("page") String page, 
                              @Body ReceiptRequestPayload receiptRequestPayload);
```

Calling API

```
Call<cutomObject> responseCall = API.getData("10", "1", requestPayload);
responseCall .enqueue(new Callback<cutomObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<cutomObject> call, retrofit2.Response<cutomObject> response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Receipts"+response);
        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Receipts"+response.body());
    }
    @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ReceiptList> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

But it's not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "_it's not working_" is not very helpful. Do you get any errors? Exceptions? Bad request? Bad response? What _exactly_ is the problem?

Comment: No I am not getting any errors and exceptions. Actually the enqueue method itself is not executing. If I pass only request payload object that time enqueue method executing and throwing error, getting repose with 304

Comment: That still does not explain what _is_ happening. Basically, how do you know "it's not working"?

Comment: It's not coming inside enqueue and even not throwing any error message.

Comment: You won't get any response since you're only logging the response in `onResponse()` - In order words, you're only printing out the response if your request was successful. You should log the response in `onFailure(...)` too, then post the response her.

Comment: @DevMike Even I'm not getting anything in onFailure(..)

Comment: I have found out the issue, actually in modal class I was declaring wrong datatype. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Use [OkHttp Logging Interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) to log your HTTP request and response data

Comment: This suppose to be a comment, not an answer.